# How to type Ctrl-^?

Tags: keyboard

I'm a bit embarrassed of asking this, but how to make the `^` (I can't see it in my keyboard).

I want to do this: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>^</kbd>

Comment: What keyboard layout do you use? where it is on the keyboard (if it exists at all) will depend on which country you are in and what layout the keyboard uses.

Comment: Not what you're asking, but in other situations the caret is often used to indicate the Control or Ctrl key. Like Ctrl-L might be shown as ^L (or other lookalike characters, such as Unicode's U+2303 on a Mac: ⌃L).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `^` character (which looks like an inverted V) is known as caret. It's also known as a [hat, control or uparrow](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Caret+(computer)).

It's <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> on my UK keyboard, and I think it's the same for US layouts as well, so you could try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>

If you have a different layout you could have a look at [this page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout) which has pictures of many different keyboard layouts.

If you're on Windows you can get a `^` by hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and typing <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> on your numeric keypad which will work for all layouts, but unfortunately this won't work if you're holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#How_control_characters_map_to_keyboards):

> Control characters are often rendered into a printable form known as [caret notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) by printing a caret (^) and then the ASCII character that has a value of the control character plus 64. Control characters generated using letter keys are thus displayed with the upper-case form of the letter. For example, ^G represents code 7, which is generated by pressing the G key when the control key is held down.

As "^" is [ASCII 94](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) (decimal), "Ctrl-^" might represent ASCII 30. Hence, holding down Alt and typing 30 on the numeric keypad *might* do the trick to "type" Ctrl-^?

Comment: Alt and typing 30 on the numeric keypad didn’t work for me (▲). Alt and typing 094 (^) did work.

Comment: @xypha, I don't think the question is about typing the ^ character, but about "typing" Ctrl+^ without actually pressing those 2 keys on the keyboard (lacking the ^ on some keyboards).

Comment: you are right @Arjan. Unfortunately i am unable to reproduce ctrl-^ and test your solution. Every time i try, it is detected as ctrl-shift-6... Hmmm.. I would have to change my keyboard layout to try it. Maybe later. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I think that (in a terminal under linux) you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> .

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>  is by default bound to:

```
quote-insert
      Add the next character typed to the line verbatim.  This is  how
      to insert characters like C-q, for example.
```

In order to verify my claim I used xxd (xxd - make a hexdump or do the reverse.) which comes with vim. I typed the following keys: 
`xxd` <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and the result looked like:

```
% xxd
^^
0000000: 1e                                      .
```

Now the explanation is a little complicated:

- `xxd`<kbd>Enter</kbd> launches the application xxd.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> sends a 0x1e. In order to understand this you have to remember that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>  sends the character code of X (0x58, note: capital X) minus 0x40, that is 0x18. In case of ^ (0x5e) this results in 0x01e
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>  terminates the input. (I don't know why I had to type it twice though).

And finally `man ascii` is really helpful in remembering all those character codes.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+Shift+6. The `^` usually represents the Ctrl key, [ie ^C for a Keyboard Interrupt], but in this case, I *think* the `^` represents a literal caret.

Answer (score 0):

The so called aschii-caret on a swedish keyboard -

hold CTRL and press the key with the caret-symbol two times

Answer (score 0):

To type caret symbol on my Italian keyboard, I had to go to
settings -> region and language -> input sources -> Italian (no dead keys)

The italian keyboard didn't work well, so I had to choose the "no dead keys" variant.

Answer (score 0):

That thing is called **Circumflex Accent** AKA **Circum Accent**

Unicode: 005E
ASCII: 94
GID: 65

Most of the times it works by pressing Shift+6 or Ctrl+Shift+6

And of course it depends on the keyboard model and the layout that you're using.

But IF you couldn't type it you can use it by adding symbols.

ヽ(ヅ)ノ